# Changing a reference to an Observable used in an Angular Template?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Is there a way to change the reference of an `Observable` used in an Angular template?

For example suppose we have this in the template.

```
  {{ ( progress$ | async ) | date:'mm:ss'}}
```

And we want to change the the `Observable` that `$progress` points to?

Is there a way to do that?

I tried a simple experiment in this Stackblitz using `setTimeout` and it just demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qxxkg9?file=src%2Fmain.ts

The code that changes the reference is in `ngOnInit`:

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.progress$ = of(0);
    }, 5000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.progress$ = interval(1000).pipe(map((c) => c * 1000));
    }, 8000);
```

The purpose of `progress$` is to report how long a song has been playing.  And if `stop` is played then the `progress$` should be `0` ... and if play is pressed again, then it should restart the timer interval ...

Perhaps the right way to do this is to this is to just keep piping the Observable through function streams that change the state to what it should be?

I tried changing the `pipe` stream [in this demo after 5 seconds](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dab7wm?file=src%2Fmain.ts) but Angular continuous to render the original stream ...

```
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.progress$.pipe(map((c) => 0));
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your stackBlitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qxxkg9?file=src%2Fmain.ts

To controll `observable`, you need to use `BehaviorSubject` or `Subject`. This is my code using `BehaviorSubject`.
This way, you can maintain a single subscription in your template and push changes through the subject.

```js
export class App implements OnInit {
  private progressControl$ = new BehaviorSubject<'play' | 'stop'>('play');

  progress$!: Observable<number>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.progress$ = this.progressControl$.pipe(
      switchMap((status) => {
        if (status === 'play') {
          return interval(1000).pipe(map((c) => c * 1000));
        } else {
          return of(0);
        }
      }),
      startWith(0)
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.progressControl$.next('stop');
    }, 5000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.progressControl$.next('play');
    }, 8000);
  }

  name = 'Angular';
}
```